# How to store the images with file path in php mysql from android

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have done with following code but it was not coming.

```
if (isset ( $_REQUEST ['s_image'] )) {

echo $_FILES ["file"] ["name"];
$file_path = "http://localhost/Onlineshopping/images/";
$file_path = $file_path . basename ( $_FILES ["file"] ["name"] );
echo "</br>";
echo $file_path;
echo "</br>";
if (move_uploaded_file ( $_FILES ['upload_file'] ['tmp_name'], $file_path )) {
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "fail";
}

/* echo "entered"; */

$base = $_REQUEST ['s_image'];
//echo $base;
$binary = base64_decode ( $base );

header ( 'Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8' );
$file = fopen ( 'uploaded_image.jpg', 'wb' );
fwrite ( $file, $binary );
fclose ( $file );
echo 'Image upload complete!!, Please check your php file directory……'; */
}
?>
```

Comment: Could you please explain your problem? If you finger long enough, they always come..

Comment: `$file_path = "http://localhost/Onlineshopping/images/";`. That can never work. So you got an echo 'fail'. Why didn't you tell?

Comment: as @greenapps states, your $file_path needs to be local disk destination and not a relative or static url. For example: $file_path = "/var/www/yourdomain.com/images/";

Comment: Could you please send the code.I am new to php